# cyberduck connecting with profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, cyberduck

I have two AWS accounts, Account A, Account B
On `Account B` there is `IAM Role` with trust relationship to `account A` and `S3FullAccess` `policy`.
On Account A I have `IAM user` configured with `access key` and `secret key`, this `IAM user` has `policy` with `assume role` to the role created on `Account B`.
Meaning, the user on `Account A` has full access to `S3` resources on `Account B`.

When I configure the `access and secret keys` on my local pc on `~/.aws/credentials` and configure the `arn_role` of the `role` created on `account B` on `~/.aws/config`, I have access to all `S3` resources on `Account B` from `AWS CLI`.

I am using `Cyberduck` to create `Presigned URLs` and I want to create the `Presigned URLs` using the configuration I specified here.
I want to have access using the cross account `role` on `Cyberduck`, as I specified.
I this feature exists? alternate options are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible  using the *S3 (Credentials from AWS Security Token Service) profile* from [Connecting using AssumeRole from AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#ConnectingusingAssumeRolefromAWSSecurityTokenServiceSTS).